# What is the path for tblexp in a .NET core project?

Tags: .net-core, f#, tlbexp

I'm trying to export a TLB file for a F# DLL.  For .NET Framework up to 4.8 the following custom build command works:

```
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
      <Exec Command="&quot;$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)\tlbexp&quot; /verbose &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;" />
    </Target>
```

I've switched to .NET 6.0 (Visual Studio 2022), and the *TargetFrameSDKToolsDirectory* is pointing to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\\
```

What is the equivalent variable to find the .NET Core 6.0 version of tlbexp?

Comment: What is wrong with the current path?

Comment: I get the following error: 
1>TlbExp : error TX0000: Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'PCDMindServerSearchStream, PCDGenericSearchStream'. Error: Type library exporter cannot load type 'PCDMindServerSearchStream' (error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: @jsparkes use `/asmpath:'c:/program files/dotnet/shared/your_sdk/version/'` to include libraries to search path, but seems that net48 version is not compatible with netcore libraries, because I get `TlbExp : error TX0000 : Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'Program, SO'. Error: Type library exporter cannot load type 'Program' (error: Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.)`

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com .NET no longer generates a TLB file.  The advice is to write an IDL file describing the interface for use in C++ clients.  Maybe I will stick to .NET 4.8 to avoid the extra work for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following project as a replacement:
https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom

This works with .net 6.0

Install:
`dotnet tool install -g dscom`

Run:
`dscom tlbexport myassembly.dll`